# Handling errors using the MongoDb-Gridfs component

Tags: apache-camel

When using the **mongodb-gridfs** component to process uploaded files to a MongoDb database, the component sets the field **camel-processed** to the string "done".

I would expect this field **not** to be set, when an error occurs, but the route below still sets the "done" value.

What am I missing here?

```
from('mongodb-gridfs:mongoClient?database=DEMO&queryStrategy=FileAttribute')
   .process{ throw new RuntimeCamelException()}
   .to('file:mongo')
```

UPDATE 1:

I have tried the below route - The exception is caught, but "camel-processed" is still set to "done".

```
onException(RuntimeCamelException.class).to("file://mongoerror")

from('mongodb-gridfs:mongoClient?database=DEMO&queryStrategy=FileAttribute')
   .process{ throw new RuntimeCamelException()}
   .to('file://mongo')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to customize the **[Error Handling](http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html)** in your camel context.
Then you can define the behavior you want when an error is triggered.

You can also use an **[Exception Clause](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html)** :

Here's an example from documentation :

```
onException(ValidationException.class).to("activemq:validationFailed");

from("seda:inputA").to("validation:foo/bar.xsd", "activemq:someQueue");

from("seda:inputB").to("direct:foo").to("rnc:mySchema.rnc","activemq:anotherQueue");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my question with it, but I still have the same problem - Is it perhaps a bug in the component?